# How to wrap an hyperlink generated with a new command with Tex4ht?

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht

I'm defining a new command to generate achromatic hyperlinks as follows:

```
\newcommand{\CNameRef}[1]{{\hypersetup{hidelinks}\nameref{#1}}}
```

It works well with the PDF output however the HTML version of the link is rendered as a normal link. Given this LaTeX input:

```
A named link to Section~\nameref{subsubsec:abney-effect}.

An achromatic named link to Section~\CNameRef{subsubsec:abney-effect}.
```

The generated HTML is as follows:

```html
<p class="noindent">A named link to Section&nbsp;<a href="AdvancedColorimetry.html#x19-590002.5.3">Abney
        Effect</a>.</p>
<p class="noindent">An achromatic named link to
        Section&nbsp;<a href="AdvancedColorimetry.html#x19-590002.5.3">Abney
        Effect</a>.</p>
```

I would like to be able to wrap the hyperlink with a `<span>` tag for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redefine the `\CNameRef` when `tex4ht` is running to output the `<span>` element. Easiest way to do that is to move the command definition to a package, say `mycommands.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mycommands}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\CNameRef}[1]{{\hypersetup{hidelinks}\nameref{#1}}}
\endinput
```

This way we can provide a configuration file for `tex4ht`, `mycommands.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{CNameRef}{2}
\def\:temp#1{\a:CNameRef\o:CNameRef:{#1}\b:CNameRef}
\HLet\CNameRef\:temp

\Configure{CNameRef}{\HCode{<span class="CNameRef">}}{\HCode{</span>}}

\Hinput{mycommands}
```

What's going on here? With the `\NewConfigure` command, so called hooks are defined. These will be later used to insert the HTML tags. The second parameter is the name of the hook and the last one is number of generated hooks. Because we want to insert tags before and after the command, we need two hooks. These hooks are special commands, named as `\a:CNameRef` and `\b:CNameRef`. The `:` character can be used as a part of command names in `.4ht` files.

The next line defines a temporary command which will be used in place of the original command. The `\o:CnameRef:` command contains the original `\CNameRef` command, it needs to be executed to generate the link. Before and after it are placed the hooks which will insert the HTML code.

The next line, `\HLet\CNameRef\:temp` is a variant of the `\let` command, which saves the original form of the first command in a `\o:CNameRef:` macro and replaces it with the temporary command defined in the previous step.

Finally, `\Configure{CNameRef}{\HCode{<span class="CNameRef">}}{\HCode{</span>}}` configures the `CNameRef` hooks with the HTML code.

It is time for an example now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mycommands}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello world}\label{subsubsec:abney-effect}
A named link to Section~\nameref{subsubsec:abney-effect}.

An achromatic named link to Section~\CNameRef{subsubsec:abney-effect}.
\end{document}
```

Here is the generated HTML:

```html
<h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">1   </span> <a 
 id="x1-10001"></a>Hello world</h3>
<!--l. 7--><p class="noindent" >A named link to Section <a 
href="#x1-10001">Hello world<!--tex4ht:ref: subsubsec:abney-effect --></a>.
</p><!--l. 9--><p class="indent" >   An achromatic named link to Section <span class="CNameRef"><a 
href="#x1-10001">Hello world<!--tex4ht:ref: subsubsec:abney-effect --></a></span>. </p>
```

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate educational all your answers here are.